# Get value from input field and store into variable or asp label control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I need to get the value from an input field that uses a jquery date picker and store it into a variable or ASP control. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Here is the code portion of the aspx file:

```
<asp:Panel ID="AppointmentPNL" runat="server" GroupingText="Appointments" CssClass="module">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="ScheduleLBL" runat="server">Appointment Date:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
                                <asp:TextBox ID="ScheduleTXT" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ScheduleDateRV" runat="server" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Date format incorrect." Display="Dynamic" 
                                    ValidationGroup="Schedule" 
                                    ValidationExpression="((^(10|12|0?[13578])([/])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(11|0?[469])([/])(30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(2[0-8]|1[0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2468][048]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([3579][26]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])(1[89][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])(1[89][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])(1[89][13579][26])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][13579][26])$))" 
                                    ControlToValidate="ScheduleTXT"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="ScheduleBTN" runat="server" Text="Schedule" CssClass="submitButton"
                                    OnClick="ScheduleBTN_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="ScheduleStatusLBL" runat="server">Appointment Status:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="AppointmentCompletedBTN" runat="server" Text="Complete" 
                                    CssClass="submitButton" onclick="AppointmentCompletedBTN_Click" />
                                <asp:Button ID="NoShowBTN" runat="server" Text="No Show" 
                                    CssClass="submitButton" onclick="NoShowBTN_Click" />
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
```

This is the code behind that stores value from text box to the database:

```
UpdateArchProcSDS.UpdateParameters["ScheduledCall"].DefaultValue = ScheduleTXT.Text;
```

Comment: using JS or in code behind ?

Comment: Can you show us what code you've tried so far, and what's not working / what you're having trouble with?  If you review the [faq] section on asking questions, and the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page, you'll see that you should always show your research / efforts when posting.  Otherwise it looks like you are making a code request and want people to do all the work for you.

Comment: I need the value in the code behind to update a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
```

and then you can get it like this

```
Request.Form["datepicker"]
```

or if you are using `runat="server"` attribute with your `input` then you can simply fetch with it's Id

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" runat="server" clientidmode="Static"/>
```

Code behind

```
string value = datepicker.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know how would be to do the following:

With the correct jquery js references in the head tag put this also in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker();
    });

</script>
```

Add your textbox control to the page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server">
```

And that's it.  When you click in the textbox it will display the calender and after selecting it will show the value in the textbox.

If you need to get the value of the textbox:

```
function GetValue()
{
  var selectedDate = $("#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>").val();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I have multiple panels with multiple text boxes that need the date picker?

Comment: You would just do the same with all the textboxes, no different.  By using the ajax call it keeps the page from refreshing too.